# HTML: div not taking complete width (only in smaller devices)

Tags: html, css

My HTML:

```
    <div id="header_row">
        <header>
            <img id="first" src="/modi_logo.png" alt="modi">
            <img id="second" src="/rrb_logo.png" alt="Logo">
            <h1>A website</h1>
            <img id="third" src="/murmu_logo.png" alt = "Logo">
        </header>
    
        <nav>
            <a id="icon_link"><label id="icon">
                <i class="fas fa-bars" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>            
            </label></a>
            <a id="about" href="#about">About</a>
            <a id="archive" href="#archives">Archive</a>
            <a id="admin" href="#admin">Admin</a>
        </nav>
    </div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>


    <div style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="carousel-container">
            <div class="carousel-slide">
                <img src="/bihu.jpg" alt="Image 1">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-slide">
                <img src="/bogibeel.jpg" alt="Image 2">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-slide">
                <img src="/tea.jpg" alt="Image 3">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-slide">
                <img src="/vande_bharat.jpg" alt="Image 4">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 20px; border: 2px solid rgb(52, 93, 226); background-color: rgb(99, 124, 204); width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;"></div>


    <div style="height: 100%;">
        <br>
        <div id="carousel-cont">
            <div id="prevButton" onclick="prevCard()"><span class="fas fa-arrow-left"></span></div>
                <div id="card-carousel">
                    <div id="card-carousel-inner"></div>
                </div>
            <div id="nextButton" onclick="nextCard()"><span class="fas fa-arrow-right"></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My CSS:

```
        #carousel-cont {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
            border-radius: 10px;
            width: 95%; /* Adjust the width of the container */
            margin: 0 auto; /* Center the container */
            background-color: rgb(52, 93, 226);
            padding: 20px;
        }

        #prevButton, #nextButton {
            border-radius: 30%;
            font-size: large;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: rgb(99, 124, 204);
            color: white;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 5px 10px;
        }

        #card-carousel {
            width: 80%; /* Adjust the width of your cards */
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }

        #card-carousel-inner {
            display: flex;
            transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
            text-align: center;
            gap: 20px;
        }
        .card {
            flex: 0 0 23.333333%;
            width: 300px;
            background-color: #fff;
            border-radius: 8px;
            overflow: hidden;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            transition: transform 0.3s;
        }

        .card-content {
            padding: 20px;
            word-wrap: break-word;
        }

        .card-content h2 {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            font-size: 1.5rem;
            color: #333;
        }

        .card-content p {
            color: #666;
        }

        nav #icon{
            font-size: medium;
            line-height: 40px;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 30px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        #icon_link{
            display: none;
        }
        .button{
            background: #fff;
            padding: 10px 15px;
            color: #34495e;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: medium;
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 6px 6px 29px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            text-decoration: none;
            transition: 0.4s;
        }
        .button:active,#prevButton:active,#nextButton:active {
            transform: translateY(2px); /* Adjust the amount of translation based on your preference */
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75); /* Adjust shadow during active state */
        }
        .carousel-container {
            position: relative;
            margin:0 auto;
            width: 100%;
        }

        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: rgb(79, 221, 231);
        }

        .popup{
            animation: slideInTop 0.5s ease-in-out;
            z-index: 2;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 80px;
            display: none;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .popup.slide-out {
            animation: slideOutBottom 0.5s ease-in-out; /* Animation duration and easing function for closing */
        }
        input{
            margin: 20px auto;
            display: block;
            width: 50%;
            padding: 8px;
            border: 1px solid gray;
        }

        .close,#close_menu{
            position: absolute;
            top: -15px;
            right: -15px;
            height: 30px;
            width: 30px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            box-shadow: 6px 6px 29px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        #close_about{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0; /* Adjusted from -15px to 10px */
            right: 0; /* Adjusted from -5px to 10px */
            height: 30px;
            width: 30px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            box-shadow: 6px 6px 29px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .popup-content{
            height: 250px;
            width: 500px;
            background: rgb(107, 126, 190);
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            position: relative;
        }
        .carousel-slides {
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .carousel-slide {
            display: none;
            width: 100%;
            animation: fade 1.5s ease-in-out; /* Fade animation with a duration of 1.5 seconds */
        }
        .carousel-slide img {
            border: 2px solid black;
            width: 100%;
            height: 400px; /* Set the height to 100% of the viewport height */
            object-fit: cover;
        }

        header {
            border: 2px solid rgb(52, 93, 226);
            background-color: rgb(99, 124, 204);
            color: white;
            height: 80px;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center; /* Vertically center items */
        }

        header img {
            height: 80px;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

        #first {
            margin-right: auto; /* Pushes the first image to the extreme left */
        }

        #second {
            margin-right: 20px; /* No margin on the right for the second image */
            margin-left: 0; /* No margin on the left for the second image */
        }

        header h1 {
            margin: 0; /* No margin for the h1 element */
        }

        #third {
            margin-left: auto; /* Pushes the third image to the extreme right */
        }
        nav {
            background-color: rgb(55, 83, 173);
            overflow: hidden;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around; /* Evenly distribute child elements */
        }

        nav a {
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            flex: 1; /* Equal distribution of space among child elements */
            position: relative; /* Added relative positioning */
            transition: background-color 0.3s ease; /* Added smooth transition effect */
        }

        nav a:hover, .popup a:hover {
            background-color: rgb(107, 126, 190); /* Adjust the background color and opacity as needed */
        }

        #header_row{
            position: fixed; 
            width: 100%; 
            z-index: 20;
        }
```

My website looks like this:

[image]

As you can see in the image (marked by red), the `carousel-container` and the div below is not taking the complete width. This is strangely occurring in only mobile devices, even though I have applied 100% width to both of them. How do I fix this? Please guide me.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Give an `!important` with width:100 and let's check.
Most probably it's work.

```
width:100!important
```